# Queueing, tagging for turn, or ask for order in turn

Tags: word-choice, sentence

How do we say if we want to be someone's next turn? Iike "I want to use this next, after your turn. Is there any simpler sentence to express it?

Comment: "May I take the next turn?" (In the form of a polite question, but really this is informing them that you'll be next, not asking their permission.)

Comment: "May I be after you, please?"

Comment: @KateBunting Don't be after me, please.

Comment: Well, all right, "After you with the toaster (or whatever)", then.

Comment: The shortest expression is simply *I'm next!* Or even just *Next!* (Of course, it would be inappropriate in certain social contexts, but fine in others.)